# Google + sign in

Tags: google-plus

I'm implementing the login using google+ account in my website. For this I used the google plus api and while singin google + I got "Error:404  origin miss match". But I provided the right origin like my localhost url.Please suggest to me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll probably want to provide information about what programming language you are using and perhaps some code showing what you're doing to allow others to help you out.

Answer (score 2):

You likely haven't set up the origin in the API console for your client ID. Make sure on the API console (https://developers.google.com/console) that the Javascript origin matches what you're using (including port number!). Note that this is different from the redirect URL - you may have set one, but not the other.

As Satal suggests though, posting some code if you still have problems would help - but I would definitely check you are using the client ID setup with the origin you expect.

Comment: Thanks for u r answer.I gave Java script origin like (http:192.168.6.13)in API console .but it is working on only HTTP not in HTTP.In HTTPS it throws an errror (Eroor:Miss match origin).After sign in how to retrieve the data about sign in user.please provide some code for retreving the data after sign in.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You'll need to add HTTPS as a separate origin. You can see how to retrieve the user data here: https://developers.google.com/+/web/people/#retrieve_profile_information

Comment: Thanks for u r response .I'll need to add HTTPS as a separate origin.I tried the above link.It is working only in java script.But I want to store the user information in my web appliction (JAvA).After getting the full information I will dasplay the sign in information as of my wish.Thanks in advance.